# Chart.js Partly filled in area/line graph

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to create a line/area graph which can be filled in up to a certain point. My best solution so far has two major problems. 1, The last curve does not match up with the fill in. 2, I can only fill in data up to an exact axis. I can't fill up to 17.5, I must do it exactly on a data point.
My best attempt: https://codepen.io/MyPenAccount/pen/XWpXyJy

[image: My attempt]

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

const colors = {
  darkBlue: {
    fill: '#92bed2',
    stroke: '#3282bf',
  }
};

const data1 = [26, 36, 42, 38, 40, 30, 12];
const data2 = [26, 36, 42, 38, 40, null, null];

const xData = [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19];

const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: xData,
    datasets: [{
      label: "Data2",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: colors.darkBlue.fill,
      pointBackgroundColor: colors.darkBlue.stroke,
      borderColor: colors.darkBlue.stroke,
      pointHighlightStroke: colors.darkBlue.stroke,
      data: data2,
    }, {
      label: "Data1",
      fill: false,
      data: data1,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: false,
      }]
    },
    animation: {
      duration: 0,
    },
  }
});
```

I can use null points in Data1 to hide that line but then it has an ugly curve and I still can't fill it up to any point other than a point on the x axis.

[image: Slightly better but worse solution]

I'm starting to think theres no solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem recently and solved it using a solution similar to yours.

Unfortunately in Chart.js there is no easy way to set the chart background color based on the zone.

***Solution.***
The solution I adopted was to create a dataset for each color I wanted to
use in the chart.

Another solution that I tried but was less satisfying is to create a bar chart, whose height of the bars was equal to the height of the chart so I could color the entire area.